nested loop messes print array logic, how do I fix it
I'm developing a Java RPG where the boss menu lists the bosses of the dungeons in pages. Once the player chooses a dungeon, the second menu lists the available actions.
    String[]heroArr={"Alice", "Annie", "Charmander", "Charmeleon", "Charizard", 
            "Bob", "Jack", "Metapod", "Butterfree", "Weedle", 
            "Lily", "Lucy", "Pikachu", "Pidgeotto", "Pidgeot"};
    int currentPage = 0;
    int pageSize = 5;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int startIndex = currentPage*pageSize;
        int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex+pageSize, heroArr.length);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            System.out.println(heroArr[i]+ "(" + String.valueOf(i+1) + ")");
        }
        
        String input = sc.nextLine().trim();
        
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            currentPage++;
            
            if (endIndex >= heroArr.length) {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        } else {
            int heroId = Integer.parseInt(input)-1;
            System.out.println("challenge "+heroArr[heroId]);
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("challenge begins! choose: 1(attack), 2(escape)");
                int usrSelectedIdx = sc.nextInt();
                if (usrSelectedIdx == 1) {
                    System.out.println("challenge succeeds! "+heroArr[heroId]+"'s fragment+1");
                } else if (usrSelectedIdx == 2) {
                    System.out.println("escaped");
                } else if (usrSelectedIdx == 9) {
                    // System.out.println();
                    currentPage = 0;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("erro");
                }
            }
        }
    }

When the player launches the game and the boss menu is rendered for the first time, everything goes well.

The player chooses a boss to challenge and then attacks the boss. However, things go wrong when the player chooses 9 to go back to the boss menu. The game is supposed to render the first pageSize = 5 bosses, but it actually renders 10 bosses. How do I fix it?


for each iteration, check what this line does (and returns) -> int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex+pageSize, heroArr.length);

Also notice that you reset currentPage to 0 when you enter 9, that means your startIndex will be 0

Does this answer your question? Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?

You can change the input type from int to String and then convert it to an int using:
int usrSelectedIdx = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());

This approach helps avoid issues related to mixing nextInt() and nextLine() in Java. The problem arises because nextInt() reads only the integer and leaves the newline character in the input buffer, causing nextLine() to read that leftover newline character immediately and return an empty string. By reading the input as a String first and then parsing it, you ensure that the input buffer is handled correctly.
For more details on this issue, you can refer to this Stack Overflow discussion.

this is not actually related to OP's question

I tried running the code and I think this is the problem. Let me know if you find any other issues.

It's not even related to the loop that causes the issue. Here is the issue: int startIndex = currentPage*pageSize;
int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex+pageSize, heroArr.length);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        System.out.println(heroArr[i]+ "(" + String.valueOf(i+1) + ")");
    } -> startIndex = 0. and endIndex seems to be 10, but OP only wants five lines printed


challenge Alice challenge begins! choose: 1(attack), 2(escape) 1 challenge succeeds! Alice's fragment+1 challenge begins! choose: 1(attack), 2(escape) 9 currentPage: 0 StartIndex: 0, endIndex: 5 Alice(1) Annie(2) Charmander(3) Charmeleon(4) Charizard(5) currentPage: 1 StartIndex: 5, endIndex: 10 Bob(6) Jack(7) Metapod(8) Butterfree(9) Weedle(10) As you can see, the loop runs a second time without waiting for input. This happens because the program is taking the newline character left in the input buffer as input. As you can see currentPage value is updating without input.

... of course it begins anew without waiting for input. You are aware of what 'while(true)' does, right?

Yes, I understand how the while loop works, but I have a question: should it stop at sc.nextLine() or not?

which is a valid question, but not related to OP's question.
